# Not sure how to use reactive values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to put data that I download inside `observeEvent` into outside variable using `reactiveValues()` so I can use it outside `observeEvent`:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rvalues <- reactiveValues(dt = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    alldata <- data_request(as.numeric(input$text1))
    rvalues$dt <- alldata
    })

  thedata <- isolate(rvalues$dt)
  output$tableoutput <- renderTable(thedata$scores)
```

But it does nothing... What am I doing wrong..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single line

```
  thedata <- isolate(rvalues$dt)
```

is only executed when the session starts (it's defined in the `server` function, not within a reactive in the server function.

First correction would be to try

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ...
  #  thedata <- isolate(rvalues$dt) ## move from here,
  output$tableoutput <- renderTable({
    thedata <- isolate(rvalues$dt) ## to here
    thedata$scores
  })
}
```

But it will not work as expected, because by using the `isolate` function, you are stopping Shiny from reacting on its change. So:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ...
  output$tableoutput <- renderTable({
    thedata <- rvalues$dt 
    thedata$scores
  })
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Well this works, but what if I want to use data from `rvalues$dt` in the rest of server function? Because I need to do some calculations out of that...

Comment: `rvalues` is defined within the scope of the `server`-function, so it can be used mostly everywhere. It is however a *reactive*, so it must be called by a reactive observer. So make your calculating function be a reactive/observer, and either use `observer` to put the results in another reactive value (allows you to abort a calculation without breaking stuff) or simply let the calculation be a `reactive itself.